# Which stack website do I ask questions about agriculture or farming homegrown food advice

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, food-safety

I started growing my pineapple plant crown from a dole pineapple that I bought at the grocery store 3 months ago. It is growing bigger and healthy everyday that goes by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a good fit for [Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange](https://gardening.stackexchange.com).

As per the site’s [Help Center](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> This site is for professional and amateur gardeners and landscapers to ask questions about the care and maintenance of gardens and landscapes.
>
> If your question is about:
>
> - the general care and feeding of plants;
> - gardening problems such as diagnosis and management of plant diseases and pests or methods for controlling weeds;
> - the practice of gardening, including timing, tools and techniques;
> - [...]
>
> [...]
>
> then you're in the right place and we'd love to help answer your question. Help us help you and tell us what part of the world you live in.

Comment: Yes. That's what I was looking for. Thanks.